# sympy tensor product of pauli matrices

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to use together sympy's `TensorProduct` from the  `sympy.physics.quantum` module and the Pauli matrices from `sympy.physics.paulialgebra`?

My problem is the following:

- physically: I have an Hamiltonian written as product of (fermionic) ladder operators and I need to implement the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation) to "translate" it to a spin Hamiltonian
- with sympy: I have used sympy's `AnnihilateFermion` and `CreateFermion` functions from `sympy.physics.secondquant`, and I have implemented manually the Jordan-Wigner transformation. The substitution from the ladder operators to the spin operators works fine. Ideally I then would use `tensor_product_simp` and `evaluate_pauli_product` to simplify the result. But sympy does not like this mixing. Any suggestions?

Below is the full minimal example. Thanks a lot for any help.

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy.physics.secondquant as sec
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct, Dagger, tensor_product_simp, IdentityOperator
from sympy.physics.paulialgebra import Pauli, evaluate_pauli_product

def JW(n, N_sites):
    factors = []
    for l in range(N_sites):
        if l < n-1:
            factors.append(-sym.I*Pauli(3))
        elif l == n-1:
            factors.append((Pauli(1)-sym.I*Pauli(2))/2)
        else:
            # add identity below
            factors.append(Pauli(1)*Pauli(1))
    res = factors[0]
    for l in range(1,n):
        res = TensorProduct(res, factors[l])
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N_sites = 4
    loci = sym.symbols('l1:{}'.format(N_sites + 1))
    chi_s = [sec.AnnihilateFermion(loci[k]) for k in range(N_sites)]
    chi_dag_s = [sec.CreateFermion(loci[k]) for k in range(N_sites)]

    H = sum((chi_dag_s[n] * chi_s[n + 1] - chi_dag_s[n + 1] * chi_s[n]) for n in range(N_sites - 1))

    list_of_subs = []
    for n in range(N_sites):
        list_of_subs.append((chi_s[n], JW(n, N_sites)))
        list_of_subs.append((chi_dag_s[n], Dagger(JW(n, N_sites))))

    H_new = H.subs(list_of_subs)
    print(H_new)
    print(tensor_product_simp(sym.expand(H_new)))
```